# ERROR warning ITMS-9000 "missing 64-bit support" How to solve an Apple warning?

Tags: ios, flash, air

Looks like AIR app publishers are going to have more issues in the new year! "Starting February 1 2015, new ios apps... must include 64-bit support and be built with ios 8 sdk."
Can someone tell me whether this can even be done with Flash AIR apps??

Comment: Adobe are aware of this and have reported that AIR will be 64 bit compliant before the Feb deadline.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/6852161#6852161

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Can you post to this page when the update becomes available?